# Problem with calibrating a PT100

Tags: calibration

I am trying to do a 12 point calibration of a 4 wire 1/10 DIN PT100 using a Fluke dry well and controller. [Accuracy of the Fluke measurement is +/-5mK]

I put a 100.000 Ohm calibration resistor on one of the channels (configured as 4 wire) and see a measured resistance of 100.001 Ohms. So far, so good.

I then take a previously calibrated PT100 (calibrated at Imperial College on a $100k machine). The calibration report shows R0 = 100.006 Ohms for the Callendar Van Dusen equation.

I then put this on the Fluke and the measured resistance at 0degC is 100.306 Ohms - why?

Comment: Different excitation currents between the King's College machine and the Fluke?

Comment: @EMFields I suppose it might be possible, but that 0.3 Ohm makes the temperature way off in that case. Something I will check later

Comment: Class A is 50mOhm. Can you alter Fluke reading with gnd'd palm of hand? I suspect CM RF noise rectification. If so, add ferrite rings around PTD

Comment: Measured current being used is 1000.8uA

Comment: 800 ppm vs 3060 ppm error

Comment: in the meantime, I might make some ice cappuccino

Comment: All measurements were made using the Kelvin 4 wire method? The connections to voltage and current path were the same? All 4 connections had a good contact with very low resistance? Are the results different if you connect a resistor in opposite direction?

Comment: @Uwe Yes. Reversing connections has no effect

Comment: How was the temperature transferred to the PT100 during the calibration at Imperial College? The temperature distribution and the temperature gradient along the PT100 resistor inside the dry well was comparable to the calibration pocess? What about heat flow through the four connection wires and a protective tube around the PT100?

Comment: @Uwe These are things I need to check. Even so, 0.3% off in a 1/10 DIN is well out of spec.

The other bit of info is that the circuit on my board is measuring the resistance far more accurately than the Fluke (at least in terms of what might be expected)

Comment: Since you're calibrating at 0°C heat flow down the wires may account for the huge +0.8°C error. If so you'll have to do 100x better to approach the claimed error in the rig. Are you at least heat sinking the wires appropriately?

Comment: P.S. Consider the use of alloy wires with low thermal conductivity. This is common practice in cryogenic work. Copper is actually better figure of merit (resisitivity/thermal conductivity), but the wires get too thin and fragile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provisionally.

It seems that the dry-well block, which is a drilled Aluminium cylinder, cannot take our small PT100 deep enough. I used one of the larger holes, designed to take a large diameter reference probe, and dropped the PT100 all the way in. The results match what I expect much more closely.

So, the answer is to have our own custom dry-well insert made to match the dimensions of the PT100s we are using